# Selecting a nested div

Tags: jquery

How do I select the element with id = datepicker which is nested as shown below?

```
<div id="section_update">

    <div class="demo">

        <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>

    </div>

</div>
```

Please suggest me a way to do this. Thank you.

Comment: `$('#datepicker');`

Comment: Actually, RTFM first please, Jquery manuel is friend of you. Also, please note that Stack Overflow is not starting point to learn a new language from scratch.

Comment: Actually SO is the easiest way to sometimes get along when you are working with multiple languages and you have poor memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you refer to 'nested' because you may have duplicated ids (you shouldn't, but...)
So, to select it just do:

```
$("#section_update #datepicker")
```

This will select the element with `id="datepicker"` that is *inside* `#section_update`

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get the value of the text field, in jQuery, you can use:

```
$("#datepicker").val()
```

e.g. to store the value in a variable for post-processing:

```
var someVariable = $("#datepicker").val();
```